# R - how to get a smooth curve between two points?

Tags: r, dictionary, geospatial, rworldmap

I'm trying to draw a line between two cities, on a world map, using R (using map and wrld_simpl).

How can I get a smooth line between the two points?  If I drew a line between US and Australia, it has three different segments

```
require(rworldmap)

map("world", col="#f2f2f2", fill=TRUE, bg="white", lwd=0.05)

data(wrld_simpl)

US_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States']
US_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States']

australia_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Australia']
australia_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Australia']

lines(c(US_lon, US_lat), c(australia_lon, australia_lat))
```

This draws a line, but it isn't correctly between aus and US.  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'smooth'? You can get a straight line just by using lines(x,y), ie with just the coordinates (dont use gcIntermediate, which does great circles).

Comment: oh I thought I was supposed to use gcIntermediate.  what other function should I use?

Comment: gcIntermediate draws a great circle - shortest distance. If that involves crossing the -180 line and your map is mercator, centred on 0, then it will probably break it into bits (can't tell, you've not given us a reproducible example). If you just do lines(c(US_lon,aus_lon),c(US_lat,aus_lat)) then you should get a straight line between the points. If that's what you want.

Comment: US_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States'] 
US_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'United States']


australia_lat = wrld_simpl$LAT[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Australia']

australia_lon = wrld_simpl$LON[wrld_simpl$NAME == 'Australia']

lines(c(US_lon, US_lat), c(australia_lon, australia_lat))


That doesn't draw the line correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you edit your q so we can see this code formatted properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `lines` takes a vector `x` of x-coordinates and `y` of y-coordinates.  Therefore your line should look like this:

```
lines(c(US_lon, australia_lon), c(US_lat, australia_lat))
```

If you want a great circle, the following will work:

```
require(geosphere)
gc <- gcIntermediate(c(US_lon, US_lat), c(australia_lon, australia_lat), breakAt=TRUE, n=1000)
invisible(lapply(gc, lines, col='red', lwd=2))
```

Comment: It's one of those 'invisible' mistakes.  You'll never see it unless you're not the person who made it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also draw a "curve" using grid.curve():

```
grid.curve(US_lon, australia_lon, US_lat, australia_lat)
```

... and you can define the "look" of the curve.